# List directory in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

How can a directory and its subdirectories be listed to display HTML files using Jekyll?

2020/nov/[16.html](http://2021/nov/16.html)
2020/nov/18/[index.html](http://2021/nov/18/index.html)
2020/nov/[22.html](http://2021/nov/22.html)
2020/dec/[10.html](http://2021/dec/10.html)
2020/dec/[12.html](http://2021/dec/12.html)

Comment: Do you want to do it by ruby plugin or with liquid (tags / filters). Something like {% listfiles "folder" %}

Answer (score 0):

You need to can create an custom [liquid-filer](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/) written in ruby. Create a file named `list-content-filter.rb` (you can choose any filename, just use `.rb` as extension, place the file inside your `_plugins` folder of your jekyll project.

```rb
module Jekyll
  module ListContent
    def echo_folder(folder)
      "Your folder: " + folder
    end

    def list_files(folder, type="*.png")
      files = Dir
        .glob(folder + "**/" + type)
        .select { |e| File.file? e }
        .join("<br>")
    end

    def list_folders(folder)
      folders = Dir
        .glob(folder + '**/*')
        .select { |e| File.directory? e }
        .join("<br>")
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_filter(Jekyll::ListContent)
```

The comamnd `.join("<br>")` will join the array elements with an HTML new line, may replace it with `"\n"` or any other char.

The last line of the plugin script, will register `ListContent` as a global filter. To use the filter write `{{ "my-folder/" | list_files: < List of parms> }}` in your markdown file.

The filter offers three functions `echo_folder`, `list_files` (with type as optional parameter; default is "*.png") and `list_folders`. Define the fuction after the `|`.

```markdown
# List content of `assets` folder

Echo just the folder

{{ "assets/" | echo_folder }}

<hr>

List `png`-files (omit parameter, use default type) from `assets` folder (recursive)

{{ "assets/" | list_files }}

<hr>

List `svg`-files from `assets` folder (recursive)

{{ "assets/" | list_files: "*.svg" }}

<hr>

List `subfolders` from `assets` folder (recursive)

{{ "assets/" | list_folders }}
```

In your case replace `assets/` with `2020` and the type with `*.html`

```markdown
{{ "2020/" | list_files: "*.html" }}
```

Comment: It's important to note that the folder listed must be relative to the Jekyll root.